# Fixing/hardening add_query_arg() usage in WP function

Tags: php, wordpress

According to [this recent post](https://make.wordpress.org/plugins/2015/04/20/fixing-add_query_arg-and-remove_query_arg-usage/) by the WordPress team, we need to check on our theme files to see if it's using the `add_query_arg()` and `remove_query_arg()` functions. Having done a full search of our current theme, I can see a reference to `add_query_arg()` in this snippet in our `pagination.php` file:

Here is PHP Code as follows :

```
if ( !function_exists( 'get_multipage_link' ) ) :
function get_multipage_link( $page = 1 ) {
global $post, $wp_rewrite;

if ( 1 == $page ) {
    $url = get_permalink();
    } else {
    if ( '' == get_option('permalink_structure') || in_array( $post->post_status, array( 'draft', 'pending') ) )
        add_query_arg( 'page', $page, get_permalink() );
    elseif ( 'page' == get_option( 'show_on_front' ) && get_option('page_on_front') == $post->ID )
        $url = trailingslashit( get_permalink() ) . user_trailingslashit( $wp_rewrite->pagination_base . "/$page", 'single_paged' );
    else
        $url = trailingslashit( get_permalink() ) . user_trailingslashit( $page, 'single_paged' );
    }
  return $url;
} 
endif;
```

Unfortunately, I'm a bit out of my depth here. Is that reference OK as it is referencing `get_permalink()` and not a URL? That's way I don't need to use the  `esc_url()` that the blog posting recommends?

Comment: then try `esc_url_raw()` ?

Comment: add_query_arg( 'page', $page, esc_url_raw(get_permalink()); ?

Comment: it applicable with current permalink, it should consider including query arguments try like in that function`return esc_url_raw($url);`